# Use Tomcat with Java SecurityManager?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, securitymanager

I'm writing a web application that is supposed to run on Tomcat on Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, Tomcat is per default configured to run with the Java SecurityManager. Besides my own web application, there will only be some well known third party web applications related to my own, like the BIRT report engine.

If one of the web applications fails or gets compromised, it may take down all the others without harm, because they all belong together. What I don't wont to happen is that a compromised web app compromises the system itself, like calling rm -r /

Do I need to use the java security manager to achieve this? Or is it only necessary to protect one web app from the other? I'd really like to prevent the effort to create .policy files for all the 3rd party web applications I intend to use.

Answer (score 3):

In theory yes.  But I've heard that people run into stacks of problems when they try to "lock down" server side code using the security manager.  Applications are frequently not designed with this in mind, and you spend a lot of time debugging SecurityExceptions until you get all of the permissions settings right.

EDIT:

I suggest that is simpler to run two Tomcat instances to avoid the problem of one application doing something that will bring down everything in a single Tomcat.  (For example, fill up the heap, leak file descriptors or ... call System.exit().)

If you still are worried about an application "breaking out" of Java and doing the equivalent of "rm /*", then you could run each Tomcat instance in a separate "chroot jail" or a virtual host.  Or you could simply run Tomcat from a restricted user account and make sure that the account cannot access / update files that it should not.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding a "`rm -r /`" doesn't require a security manager. It is sufficient if the user that runs the Tomcat process has limited access (i.e. doesn't have write access to `/` or any other important area).

Answer (score 1):

SecurityManager is just another layer of security you can apply to Tomcat and, depending your application, can be very difficult and time consuming to get right. As you've already noted, getting this right for third party applications and libraries can be even more difficult.

In my opinion, configuring this in any detail is the last thing you should be considering.

Much of this has been said already here, but if I were you, I'd follow these steps, in order:

1. Run Tomcat using jsvc under an account with the least possible privelages (by convention an account named 'tomcat', 'tomcat6' etc.). If you've installed the Ubuntu package, the init script it installed already does this, so if you start tomcat via this script, you're covered. 
   For more on jsvc, see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/setup.html
2. Run jsvc using chroot. Limit what's in the virtual filesystem you specify with chroot to only what Tomcat needs.
3. Secure your Tomcat, database and OS configuration. The Center for Information Security has good baseline guidance for this - http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform.
4. Application security. This is most important, but 1., 2. and 3. are so easily achieved by comparison that I suggest you do those before this (or better, in parallel). Ensure all input to your application is validated before it is used. Use something like OWASP's Enterprise Security API as a starting point - http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API. Everything else you do is a failsafe for your application security efforts. If your application is insecure, the machine it's running on may remain secure because of the other steps you've taken (low privilege account, chroot, secure config etc.) but the data that the application manages will be compromised.
5. Security Manager. Once you're happy that you have a good baseline of application security, by all means consider adding a security policy to your ongoing application security efforts.

Other things you can do include running an IDS like Snort on the machine to detect some intrusion attempts, running a file watcher like swatch to detect unexpected file modifications (especially to configuration files) and running various log analysers to attempt detect any other attempts at intrusion.

There's always a tradeoff to be made with any security effort. You can never totally secure your application and there always comes a point when further effort just isn't worth it. A full blown security manager configuration, for most people, falls into this category.

#### "Do I need to use the java security manager to achieve this [compromising the system itself]?"

No. There are easier ways (low privilege account, chroot, secure config etc.)